# Median Absolute Deviation Computation in R

Tags: r, median, computation

A quite confusing thing is what I got:

The **Median Absolute Deviation** output of the following vector is

```
vec = c( -5.665488 ,3.963051, 14.14956, 0, -5.665488)

> mad(vec)
[1] 8.399653
```

However, if I compute that I got the following value:

Median absolute deviation = 5.665488

which is equal to the value of the computation I have found online as well: http://www.miniwebtool.com/median-absolute-deviation-calculator/

How can the difference between the calculated value of mine and the website and the value of R be explained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with the mad function automatically setting the scaling constant as 1.482. If you do

```
mad(vec, constant=1)
```

You get the same output as your other methods