# Median Absolute Deviation in Java

Tags: java, statistics

How to calculate the [Median Absolute Deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation) (MAD) **in Java** from a list (e.g. `List<Double> list`)?

I found some implementations on stackoverflow in programming **languages I don't know** (e.g. [in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43610304/calculating-median-absolute-deviation-in-c-sharp) and [in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28506285/median-absolute-deviation-computation-in-r)) but none of them is in Java.

Comment: So what problem do you have taking the C# and R implementations and converting them to Java?

Comment: I don't know both C# and R. I don't really get why am I getting so many downvotes. Please, right after downvoting explain it in comments section.

Comment: If you know Java, you'll find it easy to learn C#, it is pretty similar. You might want to try to learn enough C# to work with the code you found -- it is useful in at least 2 ways: (1) you get a working solution for the problem at hand, (2) you have a new skill.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @RobertDodier but atm I'm really short on time! Later on I will consider giving C# a try. For the moment Krzysztof's answer did what I needed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To calculate median:**
You can use `Arrays.sort()` to sort the `input` array, then `if arrayLength%2==0` then `median` value is `(array[array.length/2-1] + array[array.length/2])/2`  otherwise the median is `(array[array.length/2])`.

**To calculate MAD:**
Create `Double[] intermediate - new Double[array.length]` and calculate the `intermediate` array using `intermediate[i] = Math.abs(input[i]-median)` for each element, then calculate the median for the `intermediate` array same way as in the first step and you're ready.

Example I've made for you:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MAD {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Double> input = Arrays.asList(new Double[] {1d, 1d, 2d, 2d, 4d, 6d, 9d});
        System.out.println(mad(input));
    }

    private static Double mad(List<Double> inputList) {
        Double[] input = inputList.toArray(new Double[inputList.size()]);
        Double median = median(input);
        arrayAbsDistance(input, median);
        return median(input);

    }

    private static void arrayAbsDistance(Double[] array, Double value) {
        for (int i=0; i<array.length;i++) {
            array[i] = Math.abs(array[i] - value);
        }
    }

    private static Double median(Double[] input) {
        if (input.length==0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("to calculate median we need at least 1 element");
        }
        Arrays.sort(input);
        if (input.length%2==0) {
            return (input[input.length/2-1] + input[input.length/2])/2;
        } 
        return input[input.length/2];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How to proceed having a list (`List<Double> list`) instead of an array? (I just edited my question)

Comment: Look at my answer again, I believe you can learn something form it :)

Comment: Thanks again for your help! Why consider the `massArray.length == 1` as a different case? Can't be included already in the "odd number of elements" case?

Comment: You're right, it is already included in the "odd number of elements" case. I believe you can also accept my answer as the correct one.